# Filling gap at bottom of studbay

Tags: walls, studs, gap

I have a large gap at the bottom of by stud bay where it bumps up against the siding. My house does not have sheathing, so what you are seeing is the siding. It is hard to tell, but the gap in the photo below is between 1/4 inch and about an inch.

My question is, what is the best way to fill this gap? I am thinking of either using a strip of wood or backer rod and putting a thick caulk or canned foam, but I am curious if there is a better or more proper way.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why does the gap vary so much? Rough concrete or rotten wood?

Comment: The foundation is concrete which is not totally straight, along with the back of the siding being a bit worn

Comment: Can you take a photo from outside. What is the siding made of?

Comment: I added a picture of the outside. I am not quite sure what it is, I think fiber cement.